# Use of weights in PROC GLIMMIX

Tags: survey, sas, glmm

I am looking to implement a generalised linear mixed model in `SAS` using `PROC GLIMMIX`. The data is from a survey, and a single set of weights is provided with the product, scaled to the population.

While `PROC GLIMMIX` has a `WEIGHT=` option, it doesn't state anywhere how the weights should be scaled (possibly, because it doesn't make a difference?)  Should I be scaling them to the sample size?

Comment: Questions that are solely about programming are off-topic for this site and may be removed.  If you have a statistical question, please edit your post to emphasize it, using [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a guideline.  If your question is about programming, see the [collection of links for internet statistical package support that we maintain](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software) and scroll down to your package.

Comment: Have you read http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi27/p258-27.pdf ? What is the random effect?

Comment: To my perception, weights are always relative, so it does not matter.

Comment: Be aware that questions about how to use SAS are off topic here. That said, your questions about how survey sample weights should be scaled is on topic. So that can be answered.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on software guidance. I have posted a question on the SAS Support Communities board, and am keeping an eye on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Regarding PROC SURVEYLOGISTIC, unfortunately, my observations are repeated measures, so I need a package that takes account both of covariance structure and weighting. The paper doesn't appear to give a clue as to whether SAS has definite expectations regarding weight scaling either.

Comment: I am aware of how to scale weights if I know what I am to scale them to, so I have decided my question is off-topic after all! (Though I'm not exactly asking how to create a table but trying to produce useful statistical analysis, but hey-ho). Thanks for all the advice though.

Comment: PS To answer one remaining question, my random effect will be the subject-specific effect (common intercept but random slopes). I will contrast it to the GEE1 or 2 marginal model. PROC GEE does not appear to accommodate survey weights (only the weight distribution parameter, which is obviously a completely different thing), but GLIMMIX can produce marginal models.